# TornadoFX: Type-Safe CSS with other libraries

Tags: css, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm new to Kolin and TornadoFX and I'm currently experimenting with some of its features. 
I'd like to use the [JFoenix-Library](http://www.jfoenix.com/index.html#start) and style its controls using the type-safe CSS feature of TornadoFX. But I don't know how to modify styles given the CSS class of a JFoenix control.

For example, the [JFXDecorator](http://www.jfoenix.com/documentation.html#Decorator) has the default CSS class `jfx-decorator`. To change the background color of the title bar I have to modify the class `jfx-decorator-buttons-container`. How can I do this with TornadoFX? In a .css file I would just use

```
.jfx-decorator-buttons-container {
  -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Is this possible with TornadoFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention the classes `jfx-decorator` and `jfx-decorator-buttons-container`, but your example CSS uses the classes `jfx-decorator-buttons` and `container`. I'm unsure which classes you really want, but I'll add the two latter, since that will produce the CSS from your example.

```
class Styles : Stylesheet() {
    companion object {
        val jfxDecoratorButtons by cssclass()
        val container by cssclass()
    }

    init {
        jfxDecoratorButtons and container {
            backgroundColor += Color.RED
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** You changed the code in your question, so here is the updated version that will produce that output:

```
class Styles : Stylesheet() {
    companion object {
        val jfxDecoratorButtonsContainer by cssclass()
    }

    init {
        jfxDecoratorButtonsContainer {
            backgroundColor += Color.RED
        }
    }
}
```

Camel cased selectors are automatically converted to lower cased with hyphens. You can also specify the exact name inside the `cssclass` delegate function:

`val myCssClass by cssclass("my-slightly-different-css-class")`

Notice also that since the `backgroundColor` property accepts multiple values, you must "add" the color to the list of colors using `+=`. This is the common pattern for all properties that accept multiple values.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I made a typo. It's `jfx-decorator-buttons-container`, a single class.

Comment: Thank, that's the solution! I couldn't find this information in the guide, maybe I missed it.

Comment: You're welcome :) The CSS chapter of the guide mentions this, but it is not a complete reference to the type safe CSS support yet. We plan to expand the chapter shortly. https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/6.%20CSS.html